# 'node_modules' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

Tags: node.js, gulp

`yarn run production`を実行すると、
途中までgulpは動いているような・・しかしエラーも出てきます。
これはどうしてでしょうか？

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Git2>yarn run production
yarn run v1.3.2
(node:12924) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
$ gulp scss && NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
[10:46:00] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Git2\gulpfile.js
[10:46:00] Starting 'scss:pc'...
[10:46:00] Starting 'scss:sp'...
[10:46:01] Finished 'scss:pc' after 1.41 s
[10:46:01] Finished 'scss:sp' after 1.41 s
[10:46:01] Starting 'scss'...
[10:46:01] Finished 'scss' after 41 μs
'node_modules' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

● 解決のためやってみたことは2点です。

①[DEP0005]... で検索してみる

これはエラーではありません。バッファを作成するこの方法は推奨されないことを警告するものです。と。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165333/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues

②'node_modules' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、..で検索してみる
　
・パスを通していないのが問題？
ここに倣ってパス末尾の\を削除し、コマンドプロンプトを再起動して再度実行しても変わらず。
http://webdev.jp.net/windows-nodejs-path/

・winなので、パスのセパレータをバックスラッシュにすれば動く？
package.jsonの  "scripts": { 以下を下記サイトにならって修正するも別のエラーになったので、これが原因ではないようです。
http://iakio.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/12/08/175457

● 各バージョンは下記のようになっています。

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Git2>node -v
v10.14.2

C:\Users\User\Documents\Git2>npm -v
6.5.0

C:\Users\User\Documents\Git2>yarn -v
1.3.2

C:\Users\User\Documents\Git2>gulp -v
[10:45:09] CLI version 3.9.1
[10:45:09] Local version 3.9.1
```

pcのOSはWin10 Proです。
nodeについてはまるっきり初心者ですので、言葉足らずなところがございましたらご指摘下さい。

どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

質問者です。すみません
結局windows なのが原因だったようで、package.jsonのpathのところにある” を\でエスケープしてみたところ解決したようです。
閲覧くださった方々、ありがとうございます。